# obtener rutas absolutas

Tags: java, rutas

Cuando ejecuto el siguiente código

```
String nombreArchivo = "archivo.pdf";
File archivoPDF = new File(nombreArchivo);
System.out.println(archivoPDF.getCanonicalPath());
```

En vez de traerme la ruta del archivo que está */home/prueba/descargas/archivo.pdf* me trae solo la ruta del proyecto en el que estoy trabajando */home/proyecto/java/desarrollo*
y dentro de esa ruta no esta el archivo.
Independientemente de lo que ponga siempre me trae la ruta del proyecto.

Answer (score 1):

Se debe a que, como en la mayoría de lenguajes, al indicar una ruta relativa (en este caso, el nombre del archivo sin más)...

```
String nombreArchivo = "archivo.pdf";
```

...se toma por defecto el directorio actual de trabajo (el directorio desde el que ejecutas el programa).

Si no, el programa no tiene manera de saber a qué archivo de todo tu sistema de ficheros quieres referirte.

*Además, ten en cuenta que el hecho de que te permita instanciar el objeto, no significa que el archivo exista. Únicamente está creando un objeto que representa la ruta de un archivo del sistema de ficheros para manipularlo de diferentes maneras. Y esto no solo se limita a leer o escribir su contenido, sino también crearlo entre otras operaciones.*

Puedes comprobar si el archivo existe con `archivoPDF.exists();`.

---

Suponiendo que tu programa está en */home/proyecto/java/desarrollo/Programa.class* y tu archivo en */home/prueba/descargas/archivo.pdf*

Si te encuentras en el directorio de desarrollo al ejecutar tu programa (o en cualquier otro que no sea el directorio de tu archivo pdf):

```
user@host:/home/proyecto/java/desarrollo$ java Programa
```

La ruta del objeto `archivoPDF` será `/home/proyecto/java/desarrollo/archivo.pdf`.

En cambio, si ejecutas el programa desde el directorio donde se encuentra tu archivo (hay que indicar el `classpath` para ejecutar un programa desde un directorio diferente):

```
user@host:/home/prueba/descargas$ java -classpath /home/proyecto/java/desarrollo Programa
```

La ruta del objeto `archivoPDF` será `/home/prueba/descargas/archivo.pdf`.

---

Luego la solución pasa por corregir la ruta al fichero indicando ruta absoluta:

```
String nombreArchivo = "/home/prueba/descargas/archivo.pdf";
```

O relativa:

```
String nombreArchivo = "../../../prueba/descargas/archivo.pdf";
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crearte un método al cual le pasas el directorio `/home` y el nombre del archivo a buscar y que te devuelva la ruta completa en la que está ese fichero.

**Ejemplo:**

Quiero la ruta de mi fichero PDF llamado: *EffectiveJava.pdf*

```
String fileName = "EffectiveJava.pdf";
```

Hago la llamada al método indicando el directorio y nombre de fichero a buscar:

```
 Path filePath = getFilePath(Paths.get("/home"), fileName);
```

Este método tendrá un `stream` que recorrerá todos los directorios a partir de `/home` para encontrar tu fichero:

```
 private static Path getFilePath(Path startingDir, String fileName) {
        try {
            return Files.walk(startingDir)
                    .filter(path -> path.getFileName().toString().equals(fileName))
                    .findFirst()
                    .orElse(null);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Código completo:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class FindFilePDF {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String fileName = "EffectiveJava.pdf";
        Path filePath = getFilePath(Paths.get("/home"), fileName);
        
        if (filePath != null) {
            System.out.println("Ruta del fichero: " + filePath);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Fichero no encontrado");
        }
    }

    private static Path getFilePath(Path startingDir, String fileName) {
        try {
            return Files.walk(startingDir)
                    .filter(path -> path.getFileName().toString().equals(fileName))
                    .findFirst()
                    .orElse(null);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Salida al ejecutar el programa:**

> Ruta del fichero: /home/devmind/Descargas/EffectiveJava.pdf